# Puzzle Type for employment test

Tags: puzzle-identification

I am taking a logic test for employment. I'm trying to find practice questions to help me prepare.  The type of questions on the test are, for example:

> 5 people are in line, George is ahead of Jim who is directly behind Sally. Tom is before Alan but behind George.

What can you determine from the question:

A: Sally is first in line
B: Sally is 5th in line
C: George is ahead of Jim
D: Jim is 1st in line
E: Sally doesn't like Tom

Can anyone tell me what type of puzzle this is and where I could find practice examples.

Comment: Basically logical deduction. Just google that

Comment: If you are older than about 10...you are about as capable as you will ever be as far as being logical is concerned.  Practicing puzzles should only benefit you to the extent that recognition can help.  A year or two of intense training in logic puzzle solving might help.  If you are looking for a job that requires a lot of natural logical analytical thinking and you get it by "studying" how will you be able to keep that job?

Comment: To be fair, one of the answers is already directly stated in this question...

Comment: Disagree with your logic capability capping at 10 years old. It's not about the ability to think laterally, it's about being exposed to more scenarios and patterns, which can only be gained through experience. The techniques you use to deduce logical statements will also evolve and multiply. Just like any other skill, the difference between being able to do something and mastering it is practice.

Comment: Try googling "interview puzzles". There are lots of different types that show up and you should find what you're looking for. Maybe you'll find something you didn't know you were looking for.

Comment: These are typically under the class of "logical reasoning" or similar.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is a a type of [logic grid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_puzzle#Logic_grid_puzzles) puzzle. It would be a simple grid with names on one side and position in line on the other, but it *does* fit that pattern. More complicated grid puzzles are sometimes called "Zebra Puzzles" because of a famous - and difficult - one [published in 1962](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zebra_Puzzle). I don't think there's a special name for the puzzle format of "there are things in an order and here are clues to figure out that order".

There are [lots of kinds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Logic_puzzles) of logic puzzles. If you want to get better at solving this exact type of puzzle, [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=solving+logic+grid+puzzles) has suggestions and you can look at the [logic grid puzzles on Puzzling](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logic-grid). If you want to get a feel for logic puzzles in general, I can recommend a few good ones:

- [Blue Eyes Problem](https://xkcd.com/blue_eyes.html) ([Solution](https://xkcd.com/solution.html))
- [The Hardest Logic Puzzle Ever](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hardest_Logic_Puzzle_Ever)
- [Prisoners and hats puzzle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prisoners_and_hats_puzzle)
- [The 1000+ logical deduction puzzles on this site](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/logical-deduction?sort=votes)

Answer (score 1):

I don't think this is a puzzle. This seems to be a [reading comprehension](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reading_comprehension) test, where the ability to understand the text and make basic deductions is assessed. You can do this without determining the exact set-up of the line:

A: *Sally is first in line.* This is **false**, because George is (somewhere) ahead of Jim, but Sally is directly before Jim, so George must be before Sally.

B: *Sally is 5th in line*. This is also **false**, because Sally is right before Jim, so she can't be the last of in a line of five people.

C: *George is ahead of Jim*. This is **true** and directly stated in the problem.

D: *Jim is 1st in line*. This is **false**, because George is ahead of Jim.

E: *Sally doesn't like Tom*. This is something we **don't know**. The text just talks about the relative positions of the people, from which we can't derive anything about the relationship between them. We don't even know whether Sally and Jim know each other.

The only option that applies is C.

The first four options test whether you have understood the text. The last option tests whether you're given to "reading between the lines" when there isn't anything there to read.

Answer (score 0):

You could try looking at practice LSATs. Although as has been mentioned, the correct answer is directly stated in the problem, so this is a lot easier than the questions on the LSAT.

Answer (score 0):

First answer is true. Option C is true. But called it puzzle is wrong. It is something like Spatial and Maths IQ test. They asked you because they want to know how fast you can answer by your logic. What is this interview for?